# Facing issue "TypeError: resolveWithMib() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)" with resolveWithMib in 4.4.12 . It was working in 4.4.4

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I am using python 2.7 and pysnmp 4.1.12 . The following code is having some trouble with resolveWithMib function. It is working with internal MIBs like SNMPv2-MIB , but not with my private MIB.

Actually I am getting "TypeError: resolveWithMib() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)" . on pysnmp 4.4.12. It worked fine on 4.4.4

I pass json objects like this

passing json object {'vmUserName': 'admin', 'partitionCpuUsage': 3.0}

```
def sendTrap_gen(self, event, eventvals):

 mibViewController = view.MibViewController(self.snmpEngine.getMibBuilder())

 # Create Notification Originator App instance.
 ntfOrg = ntforg.NotificationOriginator()
 ntfOrg.snmpContext = self.snmpContext

 trapName = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity('PARTITION-MIB', event)


 ntfOrg.sendVarBinds(
     self.snmpEngine,
     'my-notification',  # notification targets
     None, '',  # contextEngineId, contextName
     rfc1902.NotificationType( 
         trapName,
         objects={('PARTITION-MIB', k): v for k, v in eventvals.items()}
     ).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)

 )
```

The mib entry is like this

```
partitionCpuUsage OBJECT-TYPE
 SYNTAX      DisplayString (SIZE (0..100))
 MAX-ACCESS  accessible-for-notify
 STATUS      current
 DESCRIPTION
     "partition CPU Usage"
 ::= { partitionNotfsParams 7 }

partitionCpuUsageReachedTheThreshold NOTIFICATION-TYPE
OBJECTS { vmUserName, partitionCpuUsage }
STATUS current
DESCRIPTION
  "This notfication for System cpu usage reached the threshold"
::= { partitionNotfs 1 }

partitionCpuUsage OBJECT-TYPE
 SYNTAX      DisplayString (SIZE (0..100))
 MAX-ACCESS  accessible-for-notify
 STATUS      current
 DESCRIPTION
     "partition CPU Usage"
 ::= { partitionNotfsParams 7 }
```

Comment: Similar problem has been fixed in [the upcoming release candidate](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/tree/release-4.4.13). Will it work for you?

Comment: Okay . Could you let me know when this release will be available?

Comment: I hope to get it out soon. If you subscribe on pysnmp repo, you should get a notification on the release.

Comment: @IlyaEtingof Quite some time has passed since 4.4.12 is the latest release. Is there any effort made to release 4.4.13?